# ng-init for select tag in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-init

I tried to make a dropdown from a list of objects civility. But I dont know how to select the first item with an complexe object. I already do it with simple object and I don't understand why it doesn't work with my new dropdown list.

This is my select tag :

```
<select class="input-xlarg" id="listCivilities" ng-options="civility.Label for civility in civilities track by civility.CivilityID" ng-model="customer.Civility" ng-init="customer.Civility" required=""></select>
```

My list is loaded with an return of a controller asp.net MVC.

This is my model:

```
public int CivilityID { get; set; }
public string Label { get; set; }
public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
public int Order { get; set; }
public int CompanyID { get; set; }
```

So, like I said, my dropdown list load and display fine but I don't succeed to select the item who interest me.

If someone can help me to understand why it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: use `ng-model` to display selected value.

Comment: Angular example http://plnkr.co/edit/5y1JAvDoYwO52xfrRJtv?p=preview

Comment: Please check updates, I added working plunker in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-model` as  `customer.CivilityID` to bind CivilityID on selection.

and

`civility.Label for civility.CivilityID in civilities` in `ng-options`

Use this Selected Tag :

```
<select class="input-xlarg" id="listCivilities" ng-model="customer.CivilityID" ng-options="civility.Label for civility.CivilityID in civilities track by civility.CivilityID" required=""></select>
```

in Controller :

```
$scope.customer = {CivilityID : 1};
```

Updates : here is working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SOtkszPsvfqy5n45Kihu?p=preview)

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work and my dropdown list doesn't load with your tag. Moreover, $scope.customer is an object with several property.

Comment: let me create plunker for you.